# Jenkins - Publish over CIFS Plugin errors

Tags: jenkins-plugins, cifs

My Jenkins workspace is `D:\Jenkins\workspace\DMKR_FCORR`

On build success, it creates a `Distribution` directory under `workspace`. Now I want only the directories within this `Distribution` directory to be copied to another Windows share.

I tried a lot of options set to Source field of the CIFS plugin. But it copies all the folders and files under `workspace` and not only the ones under `workspace\Distribution`.

Options I already tried to set source as:

- `**\Distribution\\\**`
- `Distribution\\**`
- `D:\Jenkins\workspace\DMKR_FCORR\Distribution\\**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I just tried reinstalling the plug in and below worked then as per documentation.

Distribution**

Weird that it didn't work for first time

Comment: Super weird… this plugin is not on the top!

Comment: But then I felt cifs is too slow to copy free directories. Now I just use nant to do free things like strong replace and then copy the directory to share. Its super fast

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try setting the placeholder to ",".
Also the source should be set to Distribution/**